# Can I write the data into #temp table in Sybase ASE without transaction log?

Tags: transactions, sybase

The usual advice to speed up populating #temp tables in Sybase is to use `select into` statements instead of `insert`, since the former doesn't write to transaction log.

However, I need to populate the #temp table with the data from my application, NOT from another table, so `select into` isn't possible. Also, you can't populate #temp table via bcp.

What can I do to populate #temp table with data from the app in a way that doesn't write to transaction log?

If it matters, the app is using Java JDBC

Comment: What about building a non # temp table, and then using BCP?

Comment: @MichaelGardner - unfortunately, not an option (otherwise I'd definitely go that route)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on ASE 15.0, you can potentially use SELECT ... INTO EXISTING TABLE...; though this is not formally supported on regular tables, it works provided the table has no indexes, and the inserted table is not referenced in the SELECT part of the query; also you cannot do this in a stored procedure.

Comment: How does this answer my question? SELECT selects from existing table; my data is **in the app**

Comment: There is simply no way you can access a #temp table from a different session; it can only accessed from the current (owning) session. So you'll have to do something like BCP the data into a uniquely named table first (from a different session) and then pull it into the #temp table (from the #temp table's session) or BCP it into a common table using an extra column as a unique session identifier.